# MySQL data transfer/update to another database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpbb3

I have a forum which is here or http://neue.st/index.php

and I want to transfer the data from that forum to a new forum in a different directory http://neue.st/forums

I also only want to have select pieces of data to be transfered such as users, posts, topics, forums but not things like themes & mods

I am doing this because I kinda of screwed up the data for mods & themes for the original forum & have no idea how to reverse it because I forgot to do the backuping

Is there anyway to do this with phpmyadmin

Answer (score 2):

A good tool to use... but not absolutely necessary is PMA (`phpMyAdmin`). You should log in, click on the database you want to export data from and then click the export button.

[image]

You can see there is a "custom" choice, upon selecting that you will be presented with more options including the ability to choose which tables you need to export.
After that, head on over to your other database and import the SQL file that was generated/downloaded and happy days.

Comment: Reading the error, it pretty much explains itself. You have already got another row with the entry "1". I would drop all records of tables you are importing from the new database before the import.

Answer (score 0):

you can use SQLYog community edition, it is easy to select what ever data you want to export.

Answer (score 0):

If you download the `Support toolkit` from phpBB you are able to 'clean' the database of all non standard tables and rows (i.e. things added by MODs), leaving you with a clean database.

For themes that you no longer need, you can delete and uninstall these via your Admin control panel before removing them from your server.

If you just use 'selected' parts of your database then chances are it won't work properly because there are so many relationships between the different tables.